# Intel Rapid Storage Technology quits with iastorui.exe error

Tags: raid, intel-rst

Problem details

problem event name: bex
fault module name: isdi2.dll

Clean install
windows 7 Ult, x64

errors out with same error whether I install 11.6 or 11.7

I did the clean install in hopes of remedying it.  The drive installs, I just can't manage the raid array using the gui.

The service also won't start in service manager.  I get an error 1067

Any help would be appreciate, it seems a lot of people are having this problem on the intel forum.

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in the Intel code around the drivers being confused by non-Intel SATA on the same machine, including Windows 8 Storage Spaces (not applicable to you but might be to others who find this; it's what got me here).

The bugs are fixed in version 12.0 of the drivers. I can't find them on the Intel site but I did find them at station-drivers: http://www.station-drivers.com/telechargement/intel/sata/intel-rst_12.0.0.1083(www.station-drivers.com).exe